# Why is Phase difference linearly dependent on path difference?

Tags: waves

Well I know the algebraic proof , 
$2\pi\equiv\lambda\rightarrow \frac{2\pi}{\lambda}\equiv1\rightarrow \Delta\phi=\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}\Delta x\equiv\Delta x$
I am trying to get this in a pictorial way , which I am unable to do .
[image]

Here I have drawn a sinewave from 0 to $2\pi$ with the circles of which the SHM of individual particles are a projection of the radii moving in anticlockwise direction , How do I know that for every **unit** angle I increase inside the circle ,I'll have to make an identical circle a **unit** distance farther on the equilibrium line with the increased angle and hope to find the projection on the sinewave as it should be.

Answer (score 1):

"path difference" implies your talking about traveling waves. Then a distance traveled by a sinusoidal wave, $\Delta x$, can be converted to wave lengths, $\lambda$, by

wave lengths traveled $= \Delta x / \lambda $

which can be converted to degrees of phase difference

$$\Delta \phi = 180 *\Delta x / \lambda  $$

So from this equation you can see that $\Delta \phi$ is linearly dependent on $\Delta x$, that is $\Delta \phi = K*\Delta x$ where K is a constant.

Think of two sine waves of the same frequency offset on the x axis by $\Delta x $ the convert the $\Delta x$ into degrees (of phase difference).  Thinking of this in polar coordinates causes confusion.